# tSQLt AssertEqualsTable does not check ordering

Tags: tsqlt

I have two tables defined for actual and expected with exactly the same schema. I insert two rows into the expected table with say Ids of 2, 1.

I run

```
INSERT INTO actual EXEC tSQLt.ResultSetFilter 1, '{statement}'
```

to populate the actual then

```
EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable @expected = 'expected' , @actual = 'actual'
```

to compare the results.

Even though the data is in a different order (Ids are 1, 2 in the actual), the test passes.

I confirmed that the data was different by adding SELECT * FROM actual and SELECT * FROM expected in the test and running the test on its own with tSQLt.Run '{test name}'.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug? Apparently it is supposed to check per row so the ordering should be checked. All the other columns are NULL that are returned it is just the ID column that contains a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless an order by clause is specified in the select statement, the order isn't guaranteed by SQL server (see the top bullet point at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)) - although in practice it is often ordered as you might expect.

Because of this, I believe that tSQLt looking for non-identical and identical rows makes sense - but checking the order doesn't - otherwise the answer could change at the whim of SQL server and the test would be meaningless (and worse - intermittently failing!). The tSQLt [user guide on AssertEqualsTable](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/assertions/assertequalstable/) states that it checks the content of the table, but not that it checks the ordering therein. What leads you to conclude that the order should be being checked as well? I couldn't find mention of it.

If you need the order to be checked, you could insert both expected and actual results into a temporary table with an identity column (or use ROW_NUMBER)  and check the resultant table - if the order is different then the identity cols would be different.

There is a similar method documented [here on Greg M Lucas' blog](http://datacentricity.net/2011/12/unit-testing-databases-with-tsqlt-part-6-testing-a-select-stored-procedure/).

Relying on the order returned from the table without an order by clause is not recommended ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)) - so I'd suggest including one in your application's call to the statement, or if an SP within it if the order of returned rows is important.

Comment: "Testing the order in which results are returned" in Greg's post clears this up and confirms your explanation. I guess I assumed that AssetEqualsTable would do that. Adding the index will resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how they can use `ROW_NUMBER()` without a column in the tables to explicitly model order of insertion. @Barry King: I don't see how an index will help either. Bottom line: the tables *are* equal because a SQL table has no ordering _by definition_.